# How to load data from Cassandra to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a data which is resides in Apache Cassandra,I want to perform map/reduce jobs using hadoop Ecosystem tools.

How to load data from Cassandra to HDFS?

Is there any storage handler other than Cassandra storage handler/brisk ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a new tool from Netflix called Aegisthus which tries to address this.

> A Bulk Data Pipeline out of Cassandra. Aegisthus implements a reader
>   for the SSTable format and provides a map/reduce program to create a
>   compacted snapshot of the data contained in a column family.

- https://github.com/Netflix/aegisthus
- http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/02/aegisthus-bulk-data-pipeline-out-of.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at this project [pygmalion](https://github.com/jeromatron/pygmalion). This shall allow you to export data from Cassandra into HDFS and then use Pig latin for querying.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in multiple ways. Write a MapReduce job to read data from Cassandra and write it to HDFS or write a PigLatin script to do that. See **[this](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport)** for more info.

Comment: Infact we want to load the cassandra data for hadoop using ecosystem tools like hive/pig.Actually there is a problem we encountered in accessing the data due to Cassandra Storage Handler. With Pig it is running only in the local mode we couldn't run it in the mapreduce mode. Also we couldn't store the resultant value back to cassnadra via piglatin.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: we want to load the data from cassandra to hadoop through hive.My cassandra,hadoop and hive are open source distribution.I want embed the hiveQL query inside java. We have issues in accessing the data using cassandra storage handler. Do we have any other option other than cassandra storage handler.